# Board game design dictionary

Tags: game-design

Are there any dictionaries specific to the subject of board game design or board game culture? This would contain words describing elements found in board games or used by designers or players.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The glossary of my book "[Game Design: How to Create Video and Tabletop Games, Start to Finish](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786469528)" is 10,000+ words, but it includes video as well as tabletop game design terms.  I don't separate the two formats.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 8):

The one I'm aware of is on boardgamegeek.com...
http://www.boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Glossary

A similar one for RPGs is on the sister site, RPGGeek.com...
http://www.boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/RPG_Glossary#

I include this because many of the terms overlap, and especially for dice, are not in the BGG glossary.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for board game mechanics--what they're called and how they work--[this BoardGameGeek page](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/764516/game-mechanics-names) links to two solid lists.